# How to use R for same field aggregation by multiple separate group

Tags: r, aggregate, apply

I'm trying to perform count of an indicator on several (actually hundreds) groups separately (NOT on all combinations of all groups). I'll demonstrate it by simplified example:

Assume I have that dataset

```
data<-cbind(c(1,1,1,2,2,2)
,c(1,1,2,2,2,3)
,c(3,2,1,2,2,3))
> data

      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    3
[2,]    1    1    2
[3,]    1    2    1
[4,]    2    2    2
[5,]    2    2    2
[6,]    2    3    3
```

and an indicator

```
some_indicator<-c(1,0,0,1,0,1)
```

then I want to run without loops (like apply by column) something like,

```
aggregate(some_indicator,list(data[,1]),sum)
aggregate(some_indicator,list(data[,2]),sum)
aggregate(some_indicator,list(data[,3]),sum)
```

which will generate the following result:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    0
[2,]    2    1    1
[3,]    0    1    2
```

i.e. for each column (values subset do not change much between columns), count the indicator by value and merge it.

Currently I wrote it with a loop over columns, but I need much more efficient way, since there are lot of columns and It takes over an hour.

Thanks in advance,
Michael.

Answer (score 4):

**1) tapply**   The first argument of `tapply` is `data` with each column replaced by `some_indicator`.  The second argument indicates that we wish to group by the groups in data and by the column number.

```
result <- tapply(replace(data, TRUE, some_indicator), list(data, col(data)), sum)
replace(unname(result), is.na(result), 0)
```

For the input shown in the question, the last line gives:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    0
[2,]    2    1    1
[3,]    0    1    2
```

**1a) tapply** A somewhat longer `tapply` solution would be the following.  `fun` takes a column as its argument and uses `tapply` to sum the groups in `some_indicator` using that column as the group; however, different columns could have different sets of groups in them so to ensure that they all have the same set of groups (for later alignment) we actually groups by `factor(x, levs)`.  The `sapply` applies `fun` to each column of `data`.  The `as.data.frame` is needed since `data` is a matrix so `sapply` would apply across each element rather than each column if we were to apply it to that.

```
 levs <- levels(factor(data))
 fun <- function(x) tapply(some_indicator, factor(x, levs), sum)
 result <- sapply(as.data.frame(data), fun)
 replace(unname(result), is.na(result), 0)
```

**2) xtabs**  This is quite similar to the `tapply` solution.  It does have the advantages that: (1)  `sum` is implied by `xtabs` and so need not be specified and also (2) unfilled cells are filled with 0 rather than NA eliminating the extra step of replacing of NAs with 0.  On the other hand we must unravel each component of the formula into a vector using `c` since unlike `tapply` the `xtabs` formula will not accept matrices:

```
result <- xtabs(c(replace(data, TRUE, some_indicator)) ~ c(data) + c(col(data)))
dimnames(result) <- NULL
```

For the data in the question this gives:

```
> result
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    0
[2,]    2    1    1
[3,]    0    1    2
```

**REVISED** Revised `tapply` solution and added `xtabs` solution.

Comment: this is so nice but i don't understand how it is working. Could you add some comments to your 2nd and 3th lines?

Comment: Have simplified the `tapply` solution and added an `xtabs` solution.

Comment: Wow,you made it look so clean and neat. I chose the tapply() function. Works great and very fast.

Answer (score 1):

`melt` from "reshape2" has a method for matrices which could be useful here. Using "reshape2", the solution could be as straightforward as:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(cbind(some_indicator, melt(data)), 
      value ~ Var2, value.var= "some_indicator", 
      fun.aggregate=sum)
#   value 1 2 3
# 1     1 1 1 0
# 2     2 2 1 1
# 3     3 0 1 2
```

This answer assumes some prior knowledge of how `melt` works on a `matrix`, in particular that it will create a three-column `data.frame` with "Var1" representing the `rownames` (or numbers), "Var2" representing the `colnames` (or numbers), and "value" representing the values from the `matrix`.

Comment: Thank you so much for great idea, and reminding me of the melt for transposing data.