# How Can I check the occurences of the values in each individual in R?

Tags: r, plyr

Let's say I have a `data.frame` that looks like this:

```
ID   B
1    1
1    2
1    1
1    3
2    2
2    2
2    2
2    2
3    2
3    10
3    2
```

Now I want to check the occurrences of B under each ID, such as that for no. 1, 1 happens twice, 2 and 3 happens 1 time each. And in no. 2, only 2 happens 4 times. How should I accomplish this? I tried to use `table` in `ddply` but somehow it did not work. Thanks.

Comment: Note that for ID = 2, B = 2 happens four times, not three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And here's an `aggregate` solution:

```
> with(data, aggregate(B, list(ID=ID, B=B), length))
  ID  B x
1  1  1 2
2  1  2 1
3  2  2 4
4  3  2 2
5  1  3 1
6  3 10 1
```

Comment: @user2215913, if it works like magic, you should consider up-voting it or accepting it!

Comment: @AnandaMahto I tried to upvote or send a thank-you note but my point on Stack Overflow is too low and I am not qualified yet to do this.

Comment: @user2215913, it's your question, so you should be able to accept any *one* of the answers that best suits your requirements. And you'll get some rep in the process :-)

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you may just want a `table`

```
> table(dat)
##    B
## ID  1 2 3 10
##   1 2 1 1  0
##   2 0 4 0  0
##   3 0 2 0  1
```

Then the following shows that for ID equal to 1, there are two 1s, one 2, and one 3.

```
> table(dat)[1, ]
##  1  2  3 10 
##  2  1  1  0
```

Comment: Down-vote it all you want, it's exactly what the OP is asking for.

Comment: Depending on intended output, `ftable(dat, row.vars=1:2)` may also be of interest.

Comment: +1 for same reason as @SimonO'Hanlon and because it seems that people downvote you for no reason what so ever lately (as you posted in meta)

Comment: @DavidArenburg, it seems like there's a consistent pattern developing as far as that goes.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that too. My guess is that there's someone that doesn't like you and follows you everywhere. I was affraid of such a thing potentially happening to anyone without any real way of SO to deffend users from such abuse

Comment: @DavidArenburg, If there were a string of downvotes, there are ways that the SO system manages to detect and deal with those. Sometimes people go on a downvoting rampage when you close their question. It's happened to me once or twice, but I'm not sure if that's the case here or in the case of the question Richard mentioned in meta. I've given up on trying to understanding SO voting. My [unexplained downvote of the day](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23389481).

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach using "dplyr" (if I understood your question correctly):

```
library(dplyr)
mydf %.% group_by(ID, B) %.% summarise(count = n())
# Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
# Groups: ID
# 
#   ID  B count
# 1  1  1     2
# 2  1  2     1
# 3  1  3     1
# 4  2  2     4
# 5  3  2     2
# 6  3 10     1
```

In "plyr", I guess it would be something like:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(mydf, .(ID, B), summarise, count = length(B))
```

---

In base R, you could do something like the following and just remove the rows with 0:

```
data.frame(table(mydf))
#    ID  B Freq
# 1   1  1    2
# 2   2  1    0
# 3   3  1    0
# 4   1  2    1
# 5   2  2    4
# 6   3  2    2
# 7   1  3    1
# 8   2  3    0
# 9   3  3    0
# 10  1 10    0
# 11  2 10    0
# 12  3 10    1
```

Answer (score 1):

And the `data.table` solution because there must be:

```
data[, .N, by=c('ID','B')]
```

The above won't work if you try to apply it to a `data.frame`. It must be converted to a `data.table` first. With more recent versions of "data.table", this is most easily done with `setDT` (as recommended by David in the comments):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, .N, by=c('ID', 'B')]
```

Comment: This is not reproducible. You should write the whole code and add `setDT`. Something like `library(data.table); setDT(data)[, .N, by=c('ID', 'B')]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I don't think that's the responsibility of the person answering. The OP didn't take the time to provide a reproducible example, and most people reading this answer should be able to figure it out.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, 1- the OP did provide a reproducible data. 2- People that are not familiar with the `data.table` package would never know that they need to do `setDT(data)` at first, and will have to spend a fair amount of time in order to reproduce this answer, guarenteed

Comment: Yes, should have included all that. Thanks for the edit